# Meaning of ただ in conjunction with 今

Tags: word-choice

I was trying to understand 今はただ, which I eventually concluded must mean: *just now*. I explain it to myself as ただ emphasises the noun *now*, as *only* or *just one*. Is this correct?

While on it, I came across: ただ今, which appears to have the same literal meaning.

Do these two statements mean exactly the same thing or are there any differences in meaning or use?

Comment: But 今は**ま**だ doesn't have **た**だ...　Maybe you meant to type 今は**た**だ?

Comment: Sorry, typo corrected. The full phrase for context is: 今 は ただ、安心 して、おやすみなさい。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ただ今 is a single formal word that means *(just) now*, *(at) present*, *(very) soon*, etc. It works as a noun and as a standalone adverb without any particle.

> - ただ今より会議を開始します。(formal)
>     Now we start the meeting.
> - 彼はただ今参りますので、少々お待ち下さい。(formal)
>     He will come (very) soon, please wait for a moment.

今はただ is three words (今 + は + ただ), and there's nothing idiomatic. 今は means *(as for) now*, and ただ means *just*, *only*, *merely*, etc. For example,

> - 今はただこの写真が残っているだけだ。
>     Now only this photo remains (everything else is lost).
> - 今はただ眠りたい。
>     I just want to sleep for now.

Note that ただ in 今はただ is an adverb that modifies something different than 今 (usually a following verb).